# Including OpenGL java code in Android project

Tags: android, opengl-es, render

I have 2 java classes, `photocube.java` and `MyGLRenderer.java` using OpenGL ES.

When I started ADT New project, I got this `MainActivity.java` already present which just gives Hello World output window.

How and where should I include these two files of mine to get my Android app working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of your files describes an activity which you want to launch instead of the default MainActivity then delete the MainActivity.java, rename your file to MainActivity.java and put it where the old one was and then rebuild.

Comment: Hi Alex, no it doesn't define the activity. Both of the files just define GLSurfaceView Object and another file defines the Renderer Class. How to go ahead with that and create the activity for it or how to modify the MainActivity.java for the same ?